# How to mock LocalDateTime function parameter inside mocked service under test?

Tags: spring, testing, localdatetime

I have controller:

```
@Controller
public class testService {

    private final MockedService service;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = GET)
    public String getInfo(@PathVariable String parametr, Model model){
        BigDecimal result =service.getInfo(LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC), parametr);
        ...
        model.addAttribute("first","...");
        model.addAttribute("second","...");
        return "Page";
    }
}
```

And I want to write a test for this controller:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class ControllerTest {

    @MockBean
    MockedService service
    
    @Test
    public void shouldReturn200Status() throws Exception {
        given(service.getInfo(LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC),"1"))
                .willReturn(BigDecimal.ONE);

        MockHttpServletResponse response = mvc.perform(
                get("/test/1").accept(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)).andReturn().getResponse();

        assertThat(response.getStatus()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK.value());
    }
}
```

And the test doesn't work because of `LocalDateTime.now()`. What can be done to make it accept some kind of stub from a certain date or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

LocalDateTime.now(ZoneOffset.UTC) will give the current time which is different in the running test and in the controller.

Example:
Your test case starts, you will get localdatetime in your test case as 2022-06-05T01:11:06.028 but when the controller is called, the time has changed, it will be greater than 2022-06-05T01:11:06.028.

So, the mocking of the service method(getInfo) is not working. You will have to use Class Matchers to mock the service method.

Use this:

```
given(service.getInfo(Mockito.any(LocalDateTime.class), Mockito.eq("1")))
                .willReturn(BigDecimal.ONE);
```

It would be better to verify the localdatetime passed as parameter to the getInfo() method. You can use [ArgumentCaptor](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-argumentcaptor) to do this.